# making the background translucent

Tags: android, android-layout

I want the background of my textView or Linear layout to be translucent. I have attached an image as an example of what I want to achieve.

[translucent http://imagecdn3.maketecheasier.com/2011/03/kde-style-oxygen-transparent.jpg](http://imagecdn3.maketecheasier.com/2011/03/kde-style-oxygen-transparent.jpg)

I don't want to make the whole activity translucent but just a layout field in it. How can I get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `Translucent` theme, descibed here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: but won't setting the whole activity's theme as translucent make all the layouts translucent?

Comment: no. docs say "Or if you want the **background** to be transparent, use the Translucent theme:"

Answer (score 1):

1. create an activity
2. set activity’s theme as `“@android:style/Theme.Translucent”` in `AndroidManifest.xml`
3. that’s all

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) for more details.

Comment: This will make the whole activity translucent which I don't want as I have many layouts and I only want one of them translucent

Answer (score 0):

**For making the activity Completely transparent**,

main.xml- 
android:background="@android:color/transparent"

manifest.xml-
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

**For making activity Translucent**

```
#00FFFFFF -  Full Transparency
#10FFFFFF -  90% Transparency
#20FFFFFF -  80% Transparency
#30FFFFFF -  70% Transparency
#40FFFFFF -  60% Transparency
#50FFFFFF -  50% Transparency
#60FFFFFF -  40% Transparency
#70FFFFFF -  30% Transparency
#80FFFFFF -  20% Transparency
#90FFFFFF -  10% Transparency
#99FFFFFF -  01% Transparency
```

**Usage**- in layout.xml, 
    android:background="20FFFFFF"

here "20" is transparency and "FFFFFF" is color
Get HTML color codes from http://html-color-codes.info/